# Masonry transition-enabled not displaying correctly (Rails, c9 environment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry

I'm a Ruby on Rails beginner, following through the Pinterest clone guide by John Elder and I'm stuck on trying to apply masonry-rails and jquery.

I'm operating on c9.io and I have installed the required gems and used bundle install.

The problem I am having is that the display of my pins are still vertical and not responsive even though there are no errors displayed in loading.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

**application.css**

```
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**pins.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
    $('#pins') .imagesLoaded ->
        $('#pins') .masonry
        itemSelector: '.box'
        isFitWidth: true
```

**pins.css.scss**

```
#pins {
margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
margin: 5px;
width: 214px;
}

.box img {
width: 100%;
}
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled masonry">
   <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
     <div class="box">
         <div class= "panel panel-default">
            <%= link_to image_tag pin.image.url (:medium) %><br/>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <%= pin.description %><br/>
            </div>
              <% if pin.user == current_user %>
                <dsv class="panel-footer">
                  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %><br/>
                  <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
          </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a solution to the problem!

I just tried adding the additional lines to the application.css file:

```
*= require 'masonry/basic'
```

Adding this in is said to be optional in the textbook but they are in fact very necessary to ensure the displays work properly (in my opinion...I'm a beginner).